# import text file as matrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am very new to python programming so this might look very easy for most of the pros out there. I have a text file in the following format. I want to import only the numbers to a matrix. Meaning i do not want the spaces (there is also a space at the start of each row) and the data label.

```
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 data_1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 data_2
 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 data_3
 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 data_4
 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 data_5
 1 1 1 1 1 3 2 data_6
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `numpy.loadtxt`, which assumes the data are delimited by whitespace by default and takes an argument `usecols` specifying which fields to use in building the array:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: matrix = np.loadtxt('matrix.txt', usecols=range(7))
In [3]: print matrix

[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  2.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  2.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  2.  2.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  3.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  3.  2.]]
```

If you want your matrix elements to be integers, pass `dtype=int` to `loadtxt` as well.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for! thanks. One more question: How can i only get the first four elements of each row? or maybe get only columns two to four? how can i use range attribute for this?

Comment: Dang, I was just about to post my solution, but then I noticed yours, and yours is much better... ;)

Comment: @user3687 the argument `usecols` can be any sequence, so `usecols=(0,1,2,3)` is the first 4 rows, `usecols=(1,2,3)` is columns 2-4 etc (note Python's zero-based indexing).

Comment: @xnx If I don't know the number of columns but want numpy to find that from the newline character, what would be the syntax?